# Determine all possible number of 32KB chunks for given user memory size and offsets

Tags: c

I would like to determine the number of 32 KB chunks in a given memory block (which is always a multiple of 32KB) for every offset of 4KB, 8KB,16KB ( which is always a multiple of 4KB)

```
For ex: 
1.) Input: memory block size: 128KB
2.) Output: Overall 32KB chunks for every of 8KB : 
             Total number of chunks : 12
               Start            End
    Chunk 1 :    0               32KB 
    Chunk 2 :    8KB             40KB
    Chunk 3 :    16KB            48KB 
    Chunk 4 :    32KB            64KB
    Chunk 5 :    38KB            70KB
    ..................................
    Chunk 12:    64Kb            128KB**
```

My program

```
void determine_32Kb_chunks ( UINT64 size, UINT32 offset )

{
   UINT32 num_32KB_blocks = size / 32KB;
   UINT32 num_offset_size_blocks = size /offset;

   // Is this a valid formula ? 
   UINT32 total_numberof_32KB_chunks = num_32KB_blocks- num_offset_size_blocks;

}
```

Manual caluclation and program formula showed different results for 4KB, 16KB,etc. Can someone please assist here ?

Comment: Sure: printf out, or use your debugger to inspect, the intermediate values.  Find out which is at odds with your manual calculation and why that is.

Comment: chunk 12 starts at 96kb

Comment: yup. You are right . Chunk 12 starts at 96KB.

Comment: Any suggestions here on the generic formula that is applicable for all offsets.

Answer (score -1):

Your example worked with luck, since:

```
size / 32KB = 128/32 = 4
size /offset = 128/8 = 16
num_32KB_blocks- num_offset_size_blocks = 4-16 = -12
```

which is close enough to the requested result 12

But the formula should be:

```
number_chunks = (block_size - chunk_size) / offset
```

In your example:

```
(block_size - chunk_size) / offset = (128 - 32) / 8 = 12
```

And in code(assuming 32KB works for some reason):

```
UINT32 determine_32Kb_chunks ( UINT64 size, UINT32 offset )
{
   UINT32 total_numberof_32KB_chunks = (size - 32KB) / offset;
   return total_numberof_32KB_chunks;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . My formula defined works only for 32KB and it didn’t worked for 4kB. I am struck in determine the generic formula that work well for any multiples of 4KB offsets.

Comment: (128-32)/8 = 8 is wrong in your example above. It must be 12.

Comment: all my calculations were wrong. the result is 12. edited.